# adding a text area field to devise edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, textarea

I have an attribute called discount_info. I would like to create another field in the devise edit form, so user can edit this information. I would like to have the field be a text_area. I'm not sure how to do this in rails.

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :address, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the attribute in the `form` and ***permit*** it in the `configure_permitted_parameters` method.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :discount_info %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :discount_info %>
</div>
```

And in the controller

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  #other code
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:other_attributes, :discount_info) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.text_area :discount_info, :class => "", :placeholder => "if you want a placeholder" %>
```